Footnotes in Tables with manyfoot/bigfoot
I am currently typesetting a critical scholarly edition that features multiple footnote apparatus. Two additional foonote types are realized with bigfoot's command \DeclareNewFootnote{A} and \DeclareNewFootnote{B} resulting in the two commands \footnoteA and \footnoteB.
My problem is, that those two footnotes types don't work when they are inside a longtable environment. The footnote mark is set, while the footnote itself does not appear.
How can I make \footnoteA and \footnoteB work inside a longtable?
MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{alphalph} % Alphabetical output of counters
\RequirePackage{longtable} % Tables over multiple pages
\RequirePackage{bigfoot} % Multiple footnote apparatus
\RequirePackage[bottom,hang,stable]{footmisc} % Footnote formatting
\RequirePackage{multirow} % Text spanning multiple rows in tables

\DeclareNewFootnote{A} % This is for critical footnotes "a, b, c, ..."
\DeclareNewFootnote{B} % This is for non critical footnotes "1, 2, 3, ..."
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{\alphalph{\value{footnoteA}}}

\begin{document}%
    \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{62mm}p{62mm}@{}}%
        \leavevmode foo\footnote{Works!} & bar \\
        \leavevmode foo\footnoteA{Does not work!} & bar \\
        \leavevmode foo\footnoteB{Does not work!} & bar \\
    \end{longtable}%
\end{document}%

